# Android: AudioTrack is not working properly

Tags: java, android, audiotrack

I want to make an activity with a ListView that plays different sound effects when list item is clicked. I tested this feature with MediaPlayer and SoundPool and both work fine.

I implemented AudioTrack but when I click an item from the ListView, it only plays noise or crashes saying "Invalid audio buffer size."

Here's my code.

```
public class ATSoundAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private ArrayList<SoundData> mData;
    private Context context;
    private AudioTrack at;


    public ATSoundAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SoundData> mData) {
        super(context, -1);
        this.context = context;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        private TextView mSoundNameTv;
        private LinearLayout container;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item,
                            parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mSoundNameTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sound_name_tv);
            holder.container = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final SoundData currentSound = mData.get(position);
        if (currentSound != null) {
            holder.mSoundNameTv.setText(currentSound.getSoundName());
            holder.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    playAudioTrack(currentSound.getSoundResource());
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private void playAudioTrack(int resource) {
        int i = 0;
        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resource);
        long bufferSize = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(resource).getLength();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)bufferSize];
        try {
            int lengthOfAudioClip = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    lengthOfAudioClip, AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
            at.write(buffer, 0, lengthOfAudioClip);
            inputStream.close();
            at.play();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }
}
```

I thought the byte array size was wrong... But when I checked it in logcat, it was exactly the size of the raw file. 
I'm new to android and have no idea how to use AudioTrack.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so whats wrong with `MediaPlayer` and `SoundPool` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409811/audiorecorder-in-android-error-invalid-buffer-size -- check this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change your code

```
AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, lengthOfAudioClip, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

or else you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409811/audiorecorder-in-android-error-invalid-buffer-size)